# Ionic 3 - Change opacity of modal background?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

At the moment the opacity of an active Ionic Modal background is 0.4, I would like to change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very easily using `Sass variable` below.

*variables.scss*

```
$modal-inset-box-shadow-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)
```

**Note:** Change 4th parameter(i.e. `.4`) as you wish

Here is [**the doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

[image]

Comment: Great I was looking for that variable! How did you find it?

Comment: I've just tested this and it doesn't actually work. $modal-inset-box-shadow-color: rgba(45, 41, 78, .7);
$modal-ios-background-color: rgba(45, 41, 78, .7);
$modal-md-background-color:rgba(45, 41, 78, .7); Make no different

Comment: The same for me, the documentation does not report any sass variable to override that parameter

Comment: Are you testing on `android` or `ios`?

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Taking a look to the Ionic code base https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24modal-inset-box-shadow-color&type= seems that the variable `$modal-inset-box-shadow-color` is declared but never used. The value of the opacity is set from js code https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/7000b1b173a41eb121a0c51da41c9a00f4fc2f33/src/components/modal/modal-transitions.ts#L19 as end value an animation. So I don't think that is possible to override it without breaking the animation.

Comment: Hmm.. Hope you'll ask this feature from the Ionic team then:  https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/new @LuckyStarr